# Custom jQuery per Rails object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to create custom code that includes both javascript (jQuery) and Ruby code?

I have an undetermined amount of objects that I'm populating in a view, which are using the [jquery-cron](http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-cron/) plugin, which have to be created using ID tags instead of a class selector.  At this point, I'm just trying to create the jQuery within `<script></script>` tags at the end of the view.

> In my view:

```
<% @devices.each do |d| %>
    <div id="scan_selector_device_<%= d.id %>"></div>
       <input type="hidden" id="device_id">
       <input type="hidden" id="scan_time_device_<%= d.id %>" required="required">
    </div>
<% end %>
```

So, I may have 1 or 50 of these created depending on the amount of devices the user has.

To get this to work, I need to call the javascript to initialize:

```
<script>
  $('#scan_selector_device_1').cron({
    onChange: function() {
      $('#scan_time_device_1').val($(this).cron("value"));
    },
    useGentleSelect: true,
  });
</script>
```

I'd like to wrap the javascript in the same `.each` and create the appropriate initializer for each object doing something like:

```
 <script>
   $("#scan_selector_device_<%= d.id %>").cron({
    onChange: function() {
      $('#scan_time_device_<%= d.id %>').val($(this).cron("value"));
    },
    useGentleSelect: true,
  });
 </script>
```

However, this doesn't work.  So, how should I do this?

Comment: have you tried giving each cron object the same class? e.g `class="cron"` and just use `.each()` to initialized them?

Comment: @Marv-C Yes, the problem is the 3rd line, where I need to create the cron value.  It copies to all of them if I don't somehow target the `scan_time_device_#{d.id}` to save the value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it does work.  The syntax highlighting in my editor was making me think otherwise.  I also had to change some of the code higher up to make the initializer work:

```
<% @devices.each do |d| %>
   $("#scan_selector_device_<%= d.id %>").cron({
     onChange: function() {
       $("#scan_time_device_<%= d.id %>").val($(this).cron("value"));
     },
     useGentleSelect: true,
    });
<% end %>
```